# Convert specific string to time in PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I need to convert a string into date format, but it's returning a weird error. The string is this:

```
21 nov 2012
```

I used:

```
$time = strtotime('d M Y', $string);
```

PHP returned the error:

```
Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in index.php on line 11
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should look into [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php); example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/0b0edk. This allows you to set exactly the format you're expecting, saving you from `strtotime()`'s nonsensical parsing of American mm-dd style dates - an inhumanely stupid format if you think about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're calling the function completely wrong. Just pass it

```
$time = strtotime('21 nov 2012')
```

The 2nd argument is for passing in a timestamp that the new time is relative to. It defaults to `time()`.

**Edit:** That will return a unix timestamp. If you want to then format it, pass your new timestamp to the `date` function.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a date string to a different format:

```
<?php echo date('d M Y', strtotime($string));?>
```

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) parses a string returns the UNIX timestamp represented.  [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) converts a UNIX timestamp (or the current system time, if no timestamp is provided) into the specified format.  So, to reformat a date string you need to pass it through `strtotime` and then pass the returned UNIX timestamp as the second argument for the `date` function.  The first argument to `date` is a template for the format you want.

[Click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more details about date format options.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong function, `strtotime` only return the amount of seconds since epoch,  it does not format the date.

Try doing:

```
$time = date('d M Y', strtotime($string));
```

Comment: Initially, -1 for trying to get an extremely poor FGITW answer in. Downvote stays because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @NullUserException sorry about that. I was in the process of typing and it submitted....

Comment: All your code does is spit the input string back out as `21 Nov 2012` which is not particularly useful. OP seems to want a date format that can be used for computation, not presentation.

Answer (score 1):

For more complex string, use:

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat("d M Y H:i:s", $your_string_here);
$timestamp = $datetime->getTimestamp();
```